# About a statement in Griffiths book on Introduction to electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, classical-electrodynamics, textbook-erratum

This is what Griffiths wrote in his Electrodynamics book (Chapter 12, 2nd paragraph)

> In fact, many of the equations in electrodynamics, starting with the Lorentz force law, make explicit reference to "the" velocity of the charge. **It certainly appears, therefore, that electromagnetic theory presupposes the existence of a unique stationary reference frame, with respect to which all velocities are to be measured.**

Why should the existence of a velocity $\vec{v}$ in Lorentz force law imply the existence of a unique stationary observer? To me, what seems to matter is the relative velocity between the observer and the charge: a charge in a magnetic field could be at rest w.r.t observer A and could be in motion w.r.t observer B. For observer B, a Lorentz force will act on the charge but not for the observer A. Isn't it as simple as that?

If the velocity of some charge $q$ (that enters it Lorentz force expression) was measured w.r.t a unique stationary frame A, then two observes B and C in relative motion w.r.t to A would measure the same Lorentz force acting on q. This seems completely wrong.

Comment: The bold faced statement is false.

Comment: You wrote: "For observer B, a Lorentz force will act on the charge but not for the observer A". If an inertial observer measures a net force acting on the charge, it means that she'll observe the charge perform accelerated (non-linear-uniform) motion. Another inertial observer that doesn't measure any force will observe linear uniform motion. But if a motion is linear uniform for an inertial observer, it will be likewise linear uniform for every inertial observer! Doesn't this look like a contradiction to you? If not, why?

Comment: @my2cts It is not wrong, it's only extrapolated from its context. This paragraph is part of an introduction to Special Relativity. Note further that it only says "it *appears* that...". What he wants to say is: "From the point of view of a person who doesn't know about Special Relativity, it appears that..."

Answer (score 2):

The statement you have quoted appears in a chapter introducing special relativity. The statement is false, but serves a rhetorical purpose. Griffiths is simply trying to emphasize the apparent incompatibility of the principle of (Galilean) relativity with electrodynamics due to velocity-dependence in, for example, the Lorentz force law. This is quite poetic, because it was electrodynamics that led Einstein to special relativity in the first place.